Puppeteer Proxy with HTTP Authentication: "The page couldn't be translated" Error
I am using Puppeteer with a proxy (with HTTP authentication) and Chrome's Translate feature. However, I am encountering an issue where Chrome shows the error:
The page couldn't be translated
This is the code:
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

var gateway = {}; // my proxy

var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
  args: [...puppeteer.defaultArgs({
    headless: false
  }).map(arg => {
    if (arg.startsWith('--disable-features')) {
      return arg.replace('Translate,', '')
    }
    return arg;
  }),
  `--proxy-server=${gateway.IpAddress}:${gateway.Port}`
  ]
});

browser.on('targetcreated', async (target) => {
    if (target.type() == 'page') {
        let newPage = await target.page();
        await newPage.authenticate({
            username: gateway.Username,
            password: gateway.Password,
        });
    }
});


And this the Chrome translate feature being invoked:
Chrome Translate
Is there any additional Puppeteer argument I need to configure for Chrome Translate to work properly?
